# Which SSD type can this slot support?

Tags: memory, ssd, acer-aspire, nvme, sodimm

My Laptop make and model:
Acer Aspire A515 51G 54PF 
https://www.acer.com/ac/en/IN/content/model/NX.GT1SI.006

I wanted to upgrade my laptop so I opened it from the back to find out what my options are. I found this slot but I don't know which SSD can it support.

The dimensions are 22 mm by 80 mm,
but there is only 1 gap between the pins

[image: the slot which we are talking about]

[image: Different angle view of same slot]

It looks like NVMe, but I saw this
https://youtu.be/mgKO25ldUYg?t=331
This guy has an SSD which has 2 gaps between the pins, but seems to run smoothly after plugging it in.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. // M.2 *slots* generally have only one key.

Comment: For ram, you want to match the same stick already present, otherwise, it won't work. It doesn't have to be the same brand, but it has to be the same capacity, time latencies etc. And NVMe isn't a form factor, it refers to the interface which is PCIe x4 iirc,

Comment: “Total supported ram by Motherboard is 20GB” - This doesn’t sound right.  You might want to double check that specification.  That is an extremely odd number for the maximum amount of memory.  It would require a 16 GB and 4 GB module which an atypical configuration.  As for the size of the m.2 slot your measurements make it hard to determine anything.  You need to measure the distance from the slot to the screw hole.  That determines what size the m.2 card must be.

Comment: @Ramhound https://www.crucial.in/ind/en/scanview/001F163331D926C3
Probably that is why 4gb is soldered and there is only 1 pluggable slot

Comment: What is the make and model of the laptop?

Comment: “The dimensions are 22mm by 80mm But there is only 1 gap between the pins” - This means you have a 2280 NVMe slot.  If the users hardware looks different in the YouTube video it’s because their hardware is different

Comment: I would not make purchases based on information published by Crucial

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is Acer Aspire A515 51G

Comment: @Ramhound I am no that dumb to refer a video for different model/make laptop. He has the same model with difference in storage spec, the SSD slot in question is exactly same.

Comment: @th3pirat3 Instructions and more information: [Install m2 SSD on Aspire 5 A515-51G](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/537125/install-m2-ssd-on-aspire-5-a515-51g/p1).

Comment: @th3pirat3 - "he SSD slot in question is exactly same" - If the user's hardware has 2 slots that indicate an entirely different m.2 slot then you have.  In fact, that would indicate a SATA M.2 slot while you have an NVMe slot, those are two entirely different slots and are not compatible with one another.